# What could be causing this issue in the CK Editor

Tags: civimail, wysiwyg

CiviCRM emails don't display uploaded images to the recipients.
I think that the problem is that when I upload the image it sets the image src URL to "site/default/files/..." and doesn't include "http://www.mysite.com".
When I go in and manually enter "http://www.mysite.com", everything works.

How do I fix this so that when I upload an image it includes the base URL in the image's src URL?

Comment: @JonG, could you edit the Pantheon question & title so that it will more clearly reflect the ways in which it answers this Q.? Thx. Then I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoeMurray I considered that here - but decided against, since it's not clear to me that this is the same issue.  That said, we haven't heard back from YossiCrm, so I'm inclined to go with it.

Comment: Hey. It is the same issue but his solution doesn't solve it for me. Should I keep posting here or in the other place?

Comment: @YossiCrm The other place, we're going to close this as a duplicate.